# Can't change checkbox to be checked, must reload page to be checked

Tags: java, html, reactjs

I have a table of data, and it has checkbox field which allows people to check or uncheck it.

If i click the unchecked checkbox, it will send to database to make status of that checklist to be true, as
if i click the checked checkbox, it will send to database to make status of that checklist to be false. I have made it and do the change status in database.

this is the JSON data if i click the unchecked checkbox,
from this

```
data={"Id":"123", "checklist": false}
```

to this

```
data={"Id":"123", "checklist": true}
```

**The problem is when i click it it doesn't change the checkbox to be checked in interface, i need to reload page to make it checked**

This is my code snippet:

```
class Apps extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        blablabla:"ex"
      }
      this.onCheckChange=this.onCheckChange.bind(this)
    }

    onCheckChange(e){
      console.log(e.target.checked)
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]:e.target.checked
      })
    }
    onSubmitChecklistClicked = async (Id) => {
      var response = await RequestHandler(`${ENVIRONMENT.API_URL}api/v1.0/checklist`, {}, {Id})
      console.log(response);
    }

    render () {
        return(
            <Input type="checkbox" className="input-checked" 
            checked={data.checklist}
            onChange={this.onCheckChange,() => this.onSubmitChecklistClicked(data.Id)}></Input>
        )
    }
}
```

for the first time, the checklist is checked or unchecked is based the JSON given by database,
I dont know which one is my problem, at the onCheckChange function or checked{} attribute, or onChange{} attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the checklist to change you have to set the `checked` prop to a variable in your state. This way, when you do `setState` the component will render again and this time `checked` prop of the input would be set to false.

Example code would be such

```
class Apps extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isChecked: false, // or true depending on what you want
        ...
      }
      this.onCheckChange=this.onCheckChange.bind(this)
    }

    onCheckChange(e){
      console.log(e.target.checked)
      this.setState({
        isChecked: e.target.checked // set the variable in the state
      })
    }
    onSubmitChecklistClicked = async (Id) => {
      var response = await RequestHandler(`${ENVIRONMENT.API_URL}api/v1.0/checklist`, {}, {Id})
      console.log(response);
    }

    render () {
        return(
            <Input type="checkbox" className="input-checked" 
            checked={this.state.isChecked} // use it here
            onChange={this.onCheckChange,() => this.onSubmitChecklistClicked(data.Id)}></Input>
        )
    }
}
```